# Is there any different between declare variables ordinarily in Express?

Tags: express

I'm learning Express. Some tutorials declare `app = express()` instantly after `require('express')`, but some tutorials do it after require everything.

Is there anything different? Sometimes my app just crash or return errors because I did it in my way, but copy/paste the original order solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to `require` all of your dependencies before your code. Thats the only thing that may matter.